# $\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 \le\left(\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^2dx\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}(g(x))^2dx\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

**Question**

> Show that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$, then $\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 \le\left(\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^2dx\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}(g(x))^2dx\right)$.

I really have no idea where to start. Perhaps because of the continuity hypothesis, or
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(f^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) \leq \int_{a}^{b}f^{2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(f^{2})(t_{i}-t_{i-1}) \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(g^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) \leq \int_{a}^{b}g^{2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(g^{2})(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$

Then,
$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(fg)(t_{i} - t_{i-1})\bigg)^{2} \leq \bigg(\int_{a}^{b}fg \bigg)^{2} \leq \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(fg)(t_{i}-t_{i-1}) \bigg)^{2}$ and

$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(f^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) \bigg) \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}(g^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1})\bigg) \leq \bigg(\int_{a}^{b}f^{2} \bigg) \bigg(\int_{a}^{b}g^{2} \bigg) \leq \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(f^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1}) \bigg) \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}(g^{2})(t_{i} - t_{i-1})\bigg)$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz. Realise the integral as an inner product and you can prove it using formal manipulation, that doesn’t even recognise that you’re doing integration. Check the Wiki page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, \begin{align*}
0&\leq \int_a^b \big(\lambda f(x)+g(x)\big)^2\,\mathrm d x\\
&=\lambda ^2\int_a^b f(x)^2\,\mathrm d x+2\lambda \int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm d x+\int_a^b g(x)^2\,\mathrm d x.\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Since $(1)$ can be seen as a polynomial of second order in $\mathbb R[\lambda ]$, you have that the discriminant is negative, that is, $$\Delta :=4\left(\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm d x\right)^2-4\int_a^bf(x)^2\,\mathrm d x\cdot \int_a^bg(x)^2\,\mathrm d x\leq 0.$$
The claim follows.